# Help in synthesizing cam profile (oscillating cam and oscillating follower)

Tags: mechanisms, solid-mechanics

I am using Matlab to plot contour of the cam. So far, I understand how to use angular displacement relation between cam and follower to get the profile, pressure angle, torques etc. What I aim to do is go backwards; for a given torque vs rotation of the cam getting the profile and angle relations. How should I approach this problem?

edit1: The cam is loaded with a torsion spring that produces torque. I am considering static cases at different angles so time is not considered

Comment: How about the time and lift or opening or movement required ie rate of position change.

Comment: @SolarMike The cam is loaded with a torsion spring that produces torque. I am considering static cases at different angles so time is not considered.

Comment: Doesn't that information belong in the question? Don't bury it in the comments.